# Why is my Azure App Svc refusing to start?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have an app svc (a Web API) that I deploy in two flavours: One is "actual" and the other "simulated". The "simulated" version is identical to the "actual" one with the one exception that the API is actually calling a custom HttpMessageHandler when it thinks it's calling its backend (controlled with a compiler flag).

I deploy both of these versions to separate Azure App Services. The "simulated" svc works fine whereas the "actual" one won't start.

I get this in the "actual" (failed) service's event log:

```xml
<Events><Event><System><Provider Name="IIS AspNetCore Module V2"/><EventID>1032</EventID><Level>4</Level><Task>0</Task><Keywords>Keywords</Keywords><TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-02-10T15:36:13Z"/><EventRecordID>311623453</EventRecordID><Channel>Application</Channel><Computer>***************</Computer><Security/></System><EventData><Data>Application 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\' started successfully.</Data><Data>Process Id: 1048.</Data><Data>File Version: 15.0.20349.2. Description: IIS ASP.NET Core Module V2 Request Handler. Commit: 2670c128d522473e146ff9f8159bfffdfe694cd9</Data></EventData></Event><Event><System><Provider Name="IIS AspNetCore Module V2"/><EventID>1033</EventID><Level>4</Level><Task>0</Task><Keywords>Keywords</Keywords><TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-02-10T15:37:40Z"/><EventRecordID>311710406</EventRecordID><Channel>Application</Channel><Computer>***************</Computer><Security/></System><EventData><Data>Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/EXTERNALNEWSLETTERS-API-X' has shutdown.</Data><Data>Process Id: 1048.</Data><Data>File Version: 15.0.20349.2. Description: IIS ASP.NET Core Module V2 Request Handler. Commit: 2670c128d522473e146ff9f8159bfffdfe694cd9</Data></EventData></Event><Event><System><Provider Name=".NET Runtime"/><EventID>1026</EventID><Level>1</Level><Task>0</Task><Keywords>Keywords</Keywords><TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-02-10T15:37:57Z"/><EventRecordID>311727203</EventRecordID><Channel>Application</Channel><Computer>***************</Computer><Security/></System><EventData><Data>Application: w3wp.exe
CoreCLR Version: 5.0.220.61120
.NET Version: 5.0.2
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices, Version=5.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices, Version=5.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.AppServicesWebHostBuilderExtensions.&lt;&gt;c.&lt;UseAzureAppServices&gt;b__0_0(ILoggingBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.AddLogging(IServiceCollection services, Action`1 configure)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilderExtensions.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass9_0.&lt;ConfigureLogging&gt;b__0(IServiceCollection collection)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingStartupWebHostBuilder.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass6_0.&lt;ConfigureServices&gt;b__0(WebHostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.&lt;.ctor&gt;b__6_2(HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at api.pardot.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Source\APIs_to_the_world\api.pardot\api.pardot\Program.cs:line 12
</Data></EventData></Event>
```

So, unless I'm mistaken, the service failed at loading the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices, Version=5.0.3.0` assembly (NuGet)?

In my project this is how Azure logging is being referenced:

```xml
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="5.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices" Version="5.0.2" />
```

Two questions:

1. Is the App Service trying to load the wrong (too high) version? If so, why?
2. Why would this work in the other app service, based on the exact same project?

Comment: I've got the same error with the same references in my project. In my case though when I first published my project to Azure from VS, it worked fine. Then I deployed from Azure pipelines the same project - it deployed successfully, but the application doesn't start with this exact error in EventLog.
When I try to start the app using Kudu console it doesn't show any error.

Comment: Only after I posted a comment, I found out that there is an update for Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices. So I tried to update it to 5.0.3 and there is no error of this type anymore.